# Duplicate meeting request email

Tags: windows, outlook, microsoft-office, office365

A user says that after a recurring meeting they have, another invite is sent out again.

*There is a recurring meeting that the user has sent out to a set of users.
*After the meeting has been done, another request goes to all the users

The issue is the recurring invitations that get generated after each meeting

We have checked multiple meeting invite settings in Outlook, but are stuck on this problem.

Have already done research on the googs, everything points to IOS, however the user does not have a IOS device setup.

Comment: If I remember right, if _anyone_ with an iOS devicesforwards the invite it causes this problem. Have the original person cancel the meeting and send it again.

Comment: Ok, will check if any user is forwarding this. @NathanC (BTW this Nathan Chong?)